# Trouble putting a block quotation into a "thanks" footnote in amsart

Tags: footnotes, amsart, quotation

My major issue is that I can't figure out how to put a block quotation into a "thanks" footnote in amsart.  Ideally, I want the effect that this source specifies:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[lite]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}

\begin{document}

\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\author{John Doe\footnote{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.\footnote{Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\begin{quote}
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quote}}}}
\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```

Specifically, there is a "thanks" footnote that is a numbered footnote attached to the author's name.  That footnote itself has a footnote attached to it.  The sub-footnote contains a block quotation.

The most important aspect of this is the block quotation within the sub-footnote.  If I must, I'm willing to combine the two footnotes into one footnote, and I am also willing to have the footnote be un-numbered, in the default manner of the AMS-LaTeX \thanks macro.

No variant of this that I've tried works correctly.  Most of them produce one of these error messages:

```
! Improper \spacefactor.
! Class amsart Error: \thanks should be given separately, not inside author nam
! Use of \@xfootnote doesn't match its definition.
! Use of \@xfootnotemark doesn't match its definition.
```

Comment: Please don't add a "-- solved" to the title of your question, but just accept an answer, if it is the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tolerable solution is the following source.  It does not solve the issues I have with "thanks" being unnumbered, or having footnotes to footnotes (at least, before the body of the document).  But it does deal with the block quotation in the thanks.

The core problem seems to be that the processing of the "thanks" argument is immediately followed by some sort of tweaking of the horizontal spacing which uses \spacefactor.  However, \spacefactor can only be accessed in horizontal modes, and since the argument ends with a "quote" environment, TeX processing is in vertical mode at the time.  Normally the argument ends in text, which ensures TeX is in horizontal mode at the time.  I have no suitable text to insert at that point, but I can add "\hskip 0pt" as a no-op that gets TeX into horizontal mode.  It's possible that this fix inserts an empty line, but that would not show in the examples I have tried.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[lite]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,latexsym}

\begin{document}

\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\author{John Doe}
\thanks{Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat.  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in
voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\begin{quote}
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{quote}
\hskip 0pt
}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

\end{document}
```